# find process time in kernel routines as percentage of elapsed time since process started

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to find the percentage of time a process has been in kernel routines since time it has started. The problem is that I am not sure what arguments I should be passing to the function: `do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime()`

What am I meant to pass into this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux 2.6.39, `do_posix_clock_monotomic_gettime` is defined as such in `include/linux/time.h`:

```
#define do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime(ts) ktime_get_ts(ts)
```

ktime_get_ts is implemented in `kernel/time/timekeeping.c`. The comment above the implementation explains about the argument:

```
/**
 * ktime_get_ts - get the monotonic clock in timespec format
 * @ts:         pointer to timespec variable
 *
 * The function calculates the monotonic clock from the realtime
 * clock and the wall_to_monotonic offset and stores the result
 * in normalized timespec format in the variable pointed to by @ts.
 */
```

Comment: ok, I am trying this. I created a timespec struct and initialised it with {0,0}, and later in my module I execute the following: int time = do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime(ts.tv_sec) which I expect it to put the time in the tv_sec part of the timespec called ts however when I make the file it give the error `void value not ignored as it ought to be` as well as a warning `passing argument 1 of 'ktime_gets_ts' makes pointer from integer without cast`. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The pointer is an output parameter and the function does not return any value. Look at do_sysinfo in kernel/timer.c for an example: `struct timespec tp; ktime_get_ts(&tp);`. Also, I suggest you read a bit about pointers before continuing.